# C# Deleting RegistryKey

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to delete a RegistryKey via C#.
The key i'm trying to delete has a subkey and values.

When I try to delete it with `regKey.DeleteSubKey(name)` it says cannot delete because of subkeys.
When I try to delete it with `regKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(name)` it says that the subkey does not exist.

This is my code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(mainRegPath, true);
if(key == null)
   return;

String[] subKeyNames = key.GetSubKeyNames();
for (int i = 0; i < subKeyNames.Length; i++)
{
   RegistryKey subKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(mainRegPath + "\\" + subKeyNames[i]);
   if(subKey == null)
      continue;

   if (subKeyNames[i].Equals(name))
   {
      // both functions here just because I tried both and none is working
      //key.DeleteSubKey(subKeyNames[i]);
      key.DeleteSubKeyTree(subKeyNames[i]);
      return;
   }
}
```

When I look at it via RegEdit it looks like this:

```
mainRegPath
   name
      SubKey
```

"name" aswell as "SubKey" has values.

Hopefully u guys can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your program have enough permission (to enumerate the name key)?

Comment: yes (running as admin). I do find the right registrykey I just cannot delete it. If I try to DeleteSubKey it says can't because there are subkeys, if I try to DeleteSubKeyTree it says didn't find (doesn't exist)

Comment: Running as admin doesn't mean you have enough permission, you can use `GetAccessControl` or the permission dialog in the regedit to check that.

Comment: okay so I tried to check it, I can change values and delete them aswell, just the problem with when I try to delete it as subkey I cant because it has subkeys and when I try to delete as tree it says there's no subkey exisiting

Comment: Be mindful of 32 vs 64-bit registry.  Have a look at the methods inside of this library -- https://github.com/CodeFontana/WindowsHelpers-Net-Core/blob/master/WindowsHelpers/RegistryHelper.cs